# How to create a single instance of CLLocationManager in application?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am currently developing an iOS application using the iOS 8 SDK and Xcode 6.

My app is created using storyboards and IB. In one of the view controllers, I have an instance of CLLocationManager running that monitors the user's location in the standard way. I want to be able to use this single location manager in other view controllers as well. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Siddharth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you want to let other parts of your application knows about location updates. If that is the case you can create a `CLLocationManager` in your `AppDelegate` class and use `AppDelegate` as its delegate. Whenever a new location update occurs you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to deliver this location update to other parts of the app.